# Saving a lot of variables from a series of classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I want to save value in variables a more efficient way.
I tried writing a for loop:

```
for(i=1; i <= $('input').length; i++) {
     var x+i = $('custom'+i).val());
}
```

what i got is: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token + '
this was actually expected that it wouldnt work but i have to try before asking here

the HTML

```
<input type="text" class="custom1">
<input type="text" class="custom2">
<input type="text" class="custom3">
till custom12..
```

I know i can do this:

```
var x1 = $('.custom1').val(),
x2 = $('.custom2').val(),
x3 = $('.custom3').val(),
    till 12..
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Yes, use array `a` and access variables like a[0], a[1],a[2]

Comment: why not use an `Array` to save them?

Comment: You would need `$('.custom'+i)` to use a class selector! But if you're using unique classes, you'd better use `id`s. The class should be the same everywhere.

Comment: The most inefficient thing in this question and most of the answers is `using jQuery selector twice to get the same DOM elements`. Utilizing ``$('input')` just to count inputs and then selecting them again (moreover one by one) in a class based manner is a bad pattern.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo — I think the question is asking about efficiency in terms of lines of code, not in CPU cycles.

Comment: Let @Matthias tell us what he means, when he asks `Is there a more efficient way to do it?`

Comment: I meant writing less lines, I made it in jQuery but actually i did it in pure js. I know jquery selectors aren't the efficient way. but thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = [];
$('input').slice(0,11).each(function(index){
    x.push($(this).val());
});
```

You can omit `.slice(0,11)` if there are actually only 12 inputs on the page.

Comment: Any comments on -1 votes? We all are here to learn something. If I made a mistake, please post a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Use an array.

```
var x = [];
for(var i=1; i <= $('input').length; i++) {
     x.push($('.custom'+i).val());
}
```

Comment: Did anybody tested this answer before upvoting? No way to work in this form.

Comment: Fine. I'll put the `.` in. It's a typo the OP made that I didn't fix when I addressed the actual question.

Comment: @Quentin, still, you repeat the main mistake from the question - clearly it's a waste of resources to use `$('input')` only for counting inputs.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo – No, the main mistake in the question was trying to use variable variables.

Comment: @Quentin, indeed the question reveals, that Matthias is currently struggling with js syntax. However, jQuery selectors are intended for reuse, since parsing selectors and searching for matching elements is not cheap. You may argue that selectors here are simple and the DOM as well, but bad patterns are cloned and applied to big projects if they are not punished on time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with the variables afterwards, you could also do:

```
var results = {};
for(i=1; i <= $('input').length; i++) {
    results['x' + i] = $('.custom'+i).val());
}
```

This adds members to the ´results´ object so you can do:

```
var xOne = results.x1;
var xOneAgain = results['x1'];
var xOneLastTime = result['x' + 1];
```

Working Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mp4r5/).

Quentin's answer is probably the most natural one though.

Comment: `$('custom'+i)` does not work. Btw, an array `x` would make much more sense.

Comment: @Peter, You have created object instead of array - what for? And those 'x' prefixes to indexes only make the elements harder to access afterward.

Comment: It should be `$('.custom' + i)` (forgot the dot). Of course an array makes more sense, that's what I'm saying ('Quentin's answer is probably the most natural one though). The x-prefixes were just taken over from the variable names in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var arr = [];
var len = $('input').length;
for(var i=1; i <= len; i++) {
     arr.push($('.custom'+i).val());
}
```

Most answer's above are correct, but all evaluating `$('input').length` every time,you can increase performance by evaluating it once and assign to a variable like `len` than use that `len` variable in loop.

Answer (score -2):

```
 var x = 0;
for(i=1; i <= $('input').length; i++) {
     x += parseInt($('.custom'+i).val()) || 0;
}
```

Comment: `$('custom'+i)` does not work. Also I don't think the OP wants to sum the values, but create `n` different variables.